# Data Provider problem

Tags: actionscript-3

While running following code ,I got the error message as below,

```
function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event)
{
    XMLdata=(evt.target.data).toString();
    XMLdata=XMLdata.split("&lt;").join("<");
    XMLdata=XMLdata.split("&gt;").join(">");
    xml=new XML(XMLdata);
    **fnctn();**
}

function fnctn() 
{
    var tp:int = bulb1 + bulb2 + bulb3 + bulb4;
    if(tp == 1)
    {
        **gep.addItem(new Object());**
        gep[gep.length-1].voltage1 =evt.result.Array.Voltage.Val;
        gep[gep.length-1].current1 = evt.result.Array.Current.Val;
        gep[gep.length-1].voltage2 = 0;
        gep[gep.length-1].current2 = 0;
        gep[gep.length-1].voltage3 = 0;
        gep[gep.length-1].current3 = 0;
        gep[gep.length-1].voltage4 = 0;
        gep[gep.length-1].current4 = 0;
    }
```

Error is

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable evt is not defined.

at vi_fla::MainTimeline/fnctn()[vi_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:449]

at vi_fla::MainTimeline/urlLoader_complete()[vi_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:436]

at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()

at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()

at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

The two lines with errors are marked in the above code...what will be the reason for this error?

******UPDATE*****************

Now I have modified the code as below.

function fnctn(evt:Event)

{
var tp:int = bulb1 + bulb2 + bulb3 + bulb4;

if(tp == 1)

{

```
   ChartDataProvider1.push(xml.Value.Array.Voltage.Val.text())

ChartcategoryNames.push();

trace("value= "+xml.Value.Array.Voltage.Val.text())
```

}

}

Now there is no error while running,But trace value shows no values. It shows as Value=

How this problem can be solved?

**********UPDATE***************************

I modified code as below

var ChartcategoryNames:Array=new Array();

var ChartDataProvider1:Array=new Array();

var lineArray1:LineSeries=new LineSeries();

if(tp == 1)

{

```
                            ChartDataProvider1.push(xml.graph.Voltage.text());

            ChartcategoryNames.push();

            trace("hi= "+xml.graph.Voltage.text());

                         yAxis = new NumericAxis();

            yAxis.maximum=10;

            yAxis.minimum=0;

            yAxis.majorUnit=2;

            Exp_Content.input_mc.in_graph.verticalAxis=yAxis;

            //Exp_Content.input_mc.in_graph.dataProvider=ChartDataProvider1

                        lineArray1.dataProvider=ChartDataProvider1;
```

}

Now the trace hi shows correct values,which is also seen in ChartDataProvider1.But lineArray1 does not have any values...Please suggest a solution for this problem..

Comment: You really want to revise your naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your event around:

```
fnctn(evt);
...
function fnctn(evt : Event);
```

Answer (score 3):

As it says, in the function `fnctn`, you are using a variable named `evt`, which is not defined.

`evt` is the incoming event object in `urlloader_complete`, and so is local to that function.  Either place all your code in the event handler, or pass the event object into `fnctn`.

```
function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event)
{
    XMLdata=(evt.target.data).toString();
    XMLdata=XMLdata.split("&lt;").join("<");
    XMLdata=XMLdata.split("&gt;").join(">");
    xml=new XML(XMLdata);
    fnctn(evt);
}

function fnctn(evt:Event) 
{
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks ...I have modified the code according to your answer ...Now the error message is like                                        ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property result not found on flash.events.Event and there is no default value.
 at vi_fla::MainTimeline/fnctn()[vi_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:451]
 at vi_fla::MainTimeline/urlLoader_complete()[vi_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:439]
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: There is no property called `result` in the Event class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html.  Did you possibly mean to be reading from your XML object at this point instead?

Comment: The xml file format is as <Array>
<Voltage>16.042349</Voltage>
<Current>0.002555</Current>
</Array>....So instead of evt.result.Array.Voltage.Val; what shall I write?

Answer (score 0):

```
function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event)
{
  XMLdata=(evt.target.data).toString();
  XMLdata=XMLdata.split("&lt;").join("<");
  XMLdata=XMLdata.split("&gt;").join(">");
  xml=new XML(XMLdata);
  fnctn(evt);
}

function fnctn(evt:Event) 
{
   var tp:int = bulb1 + bulb2 + bulb3 + bulb4;
   if(tp == 1)
   {
     **gep.addItem(new Object());**
     gep[gep.length-1].voltage1 =evt.result.Array.Voltage.Val;
     gep[gep.length-1].current1 = evt.result.Array.Current.Val;
     gep[gep.length-1].voltage2 = 0;
     gep[gep.length-1].current2 = 0;
     gep[gep.length-1].voltage3 = 0;
     gep[gep.length-1].current3 = 0;
     gep[gep.length-1].voltage4 = 0;
     gep[gep.length-1].current4 = 0;
  }
}
```

try this, hope this will help you.

Comment: @Swati..I tried this code still the same error...Error #1069: Property result not found on flash.events.Event and there is no default value.....occurs